# JavaFX: How to remove Pane?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, controller, fxml

I wasn't really sure how to title this.  I have a JavaFX application in which I have two pages (fxml's) which are different sizes.  The first is 400x600; the second is maximized.  I have a return button which sends the user back to the first fxml.  I successfully set it so it goes back to the original size.  However, when I go 1->2->1->2 the screen does not maximize.   What I imagine is the issue is that it does not rerun the `initialize()` method the second time it creates this page.  Another possibility is that it is caused by the `new Runnable()` I made, which was necessary to get the `stage` object.

The second controller:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // Display
            stage = (Stage) menuPane.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setResizable(true);
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.setResizable(false);

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing all your code, it is difficult to determine what you're asking. It does sound like you have some serious flaws in your design, though. Why would you need a `Runnable` to get a `Stage`?

Comment: The way you retrieve the `Stage` from the controller indicates design flaws: The controller's responsibility is managing the node hierarchy created based on the fxml; the `Stage` is not part of this. By accessing the stage this way you put a great restriction on the potential use of fxmls using the controller: They need to be loaded on the JavaFX application thead and need to be assigned to a scene with a stage before the toolkit "regains control of the JavaFX application thread". Since a fxml is used, this just makes it extra-hard to access the documentation of that fact (if it even exists).

Comment: @Zephyr You need a runnable because it is impossible to get the stage before it loads.

Comment: @fabian So, how would you suggest retrieving the `Stage`?  Thanks.

Comment: @Riley Fitzpatrick You could always pass the stage to the initialize method. Not the best practice, but it may be an option if you don't want to majorly refactor your code.

Comment: @DustinR Okay, I'll try that out.  Why would I need to majorly refactor my code though?  Should I somehow put the functionality to change `Stage` size in my `Main.java`?

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick If you depend on passing stage to a controller, then any method that changes anything about the stage will also need to have stage passed to it. This might not matter for smaller applications, but it can easily lead to having to drag the stage around through many methods in a way that makes it less than obvious as to what the eventual use is.

Comment: I see.  My application is relatively small.  I'll try to make it more efficient.